# Extracting tags from PDF

Tags: pdf, tags

Can someone recommend a library (Linux binary, jar or source) to extract tag tree from a tagged PDF file? I tried PDFMiner, but it crashed on the first file I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with iText? Take a look on [PDFVole](http://java.net/projects/pdfvole) for an example of a project that shows this tree visually using iText. You will not be able to link the tree nodes with their curresponding page content with this appoach though.

Comment: Looks promising, but crashed on the first tagged PDF I could find (www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf)

Comment: that was webstart version, standalone jar looks fine